# Writing a non integer power in terms of integer powers

Tags: exponentiation

I would like to write $x^{2.5}$ in terms of $x$ to the power of integers, is there any way to do this. Taylor series etc. don't work when they depend on derivatives.

If it is not possible, do you have or know a proof.

Thanks

#### EDIT:

to clarify, I mean that I want to write $x^{2.5}$ in terms of a series of $x^{\mathrm{integer}}$'s, for example: $1 + x^2 + x^{3}$.
I tried to use Taylor series but since it depends on derivatives of  $x^{2.5}$ but they do not have integer powers...

Comment: What's wrong with Taylor series? Do you want a finite expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "in terms of?" It's gonna be very hard to do this.  In particular, integer powers are well-defined in the complex plane, but you get problems with non-integer powers, which need to be multi-valued. (The most obvious is the square root function, which can take +/- values, but if the exponent is irrational, you actually get an infinite number of possible values for exponentiation.)

Comment: I think he means taylor series about $0$, since at some point, the derivatives become undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was the concern. A work-around to this is to use the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ (or more generally, $\sqrt{c+x}$).

Comment: What does *Taylor series etc wont work when they depend on derivatives.* mean? When doesn't Taylor *depend* on derivatives? Can you give an example to clarify that?

Comment: I edited to try and clarify.

Comment: Okay - so you're concerned that the derivative of $x^{2.5}$ is not an integer power and that Taylor series are based on derivatives. What you are missing is that in calculating a Taylor series, you evaluate that derivative at a point and get a number that helps you find the coefficient of the Taylor series. The Taylor series itself only involves integer powers.

Comment: (And, to be clear, I'm assuming you're willing to offset, by using $(1 + x)^{2.5}$, for example, instead of $x^{2.5}$.)

Comment: Ok yes you are correct. Im am mistaken. However in this context i cannot offset x by x+1

Comment: "However in this context I cannot offset $x$ by $x+1$" - because?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^{2.5}$ can't be represented by a series in integer powers of $x$, because it is not analytic (in fact not meromorphic) at $0$: instead, it has a branch point there.

Comment: Could you provide a link to some information on this?

Comment: @EoinMurray In general, non-integer powers are "multivalued" functions in a complex sense. Branch points are points of discontinuity where the function "jumps" from one value to another.  For example, $z^{1/2}$ is the basic example of a multivalued function. $z^{2.5} = z^2z^{.5}$ is also therefore multivalued. The term "analytic function" means a function that can be written with a power series expansion. Analyticity can be shown to not hold if certain conditions on the magnitude of the derivative do not hold.

Comment: Here are some helpful wiki links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Alternate_characterizations

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point

Answer (score 1):

I'll quickly show in practice why **Taylor series doesn't work** in this case as one would think. Taylor's theorem says, that for a sufficiently smooth function we have

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\mathrm d^k}{dx^k}f(a)\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!} +R_n $$

for any $n\in \mathbb N$ and **some remainder $R_n$**. Surely we can apply this theorem to $x^{2.5}$. It's

$$ \frac{\mathrm d^k}{dx^k}x^{2.5} = 2.5^{\underline k} x^{2.5-k}$$where $2.5^{\underline k}$ denotes *falling factorial*. So for example evaluating the series for $a=1$ we get

$$x^{2.5} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2.5^{\underline k}}{k!}(x-1)^k + R_k$$

**However** we get into trouble if the think, well let's do $n\to \infty$, forget about the Remainder and call

$$(x+1)^{2.5} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2.5^{\underline k}}{k!}x^k$$
the series we looked for. We have to be sure first that the series isn't all crap and the $R_n$ contains the useful information! For "nice" functions, we will have $R_n \to 0$, but **not in this case**.

By Lagrange form, there is some $\xi$ such that

$$R_n = \frac{2.5^{\underline n}}{n!}\xi^{2.5-n}(x-1)^n.$$
Now does this go to $0$? **No,** because $2.5^{\underline n}=2.5\cdot 1.5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (-998.5) \cdot (-999.5) \cdot ...$ behaves as bad as $n!$. So while we can use the series as above, it wont't probably converge to $x^{2.5}$ as we wished.